# Antd design table column -> how to pass array of objects to dataIndex

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm fetching object (contract) from DB, it contains few fields, one of them is an array of objects (products). I have **antd** table with column Products and I would like to fill it with product names.
For example, my contract object also has account object, and the way I use dataIndex there is like this:

```
{
    title: 'Account',
    dataIndex: ['account', 'name'],
    key: 'account',
    align: 'center',
    sorter: (a, b) => a.length - b.length
}
```

That works fine! But Account is not an array.

Here is code with issue:

```
{
    title: 'Products',
    dataIndex: ['products'],
    key: 'products',
    align: 'center',
    filters: []
}
```

Here is how I map data that is send to component above which has to fill table:

```
    return data.map((contract) => ({
                key: contract._id,
                account: contract.account,
                products: [contract.products],
            }));
```

I tried returning just contract.products, tried returning `Object.values(contract.products)`, tried to `JSON.stringify(contract.products)` but then I don't know how to parse it in column and take just name...
The only way I managed to set name was by not sending object. Example:

```
    return data.map((contract) => ({
                key: contract._id,
                account: contract.account,
                products: contract.products.map(product => product.name),
            }));
```

This would indeed solve this problem, but it would made me make another asyncThunk method where I would return whole array of objects.

Hope that I described that well,this is for my college project and it's bean bugging me whole day.
I would be very grateful if someone knows how can I solve this.

Answer (score 0):

According to Antd documentation for column dataIndex, it will only accept a string or an array of strings for nested paths.

*dataIndex - Display field of the data record, support nest path by string array - string | string[ ]*

So I don't think you can pass an array of objects to dataIndex.

The only way around that I can think of would be to convert the array to a  string before passing it to your table.

To do that you can use .join() method to add space and a comma between your array items.

```
const convertArrayToString = (array) => array.join(', ');
```

And before returning you could use the above function: Example:

```
return data.map((contract) => ({
                key: contract._id,
                account: contract.account,
                products: convertArrayToString(contract.products),
            }));
```